# How to specify enum in delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, delegates, expression

My expression is

```
Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>>
```

For other primitive type

i am creating expression

```
Expression<Func<TSource,int>>, Expression<Func<TSource,string>>
```

But how to specify TResult in case of Enum

Example

```
getExpression<TSource, int>(expression)// for integer
getExpression<TSource, string>(expression) // for string
getExpression<TSource, Enum>(expression) // It reruns null

private Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> getExpression<TSource, TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            var x = expression as Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>>;

            return x;
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide more context and show the full code of you functions.

Comment: Have you tried using enum name? `Expression<Func<TSource,DayOfWeek>>`

Comment: @Sergey Enum can be any Enum. It is not specific like Gender, DayOfWeek, .....

Comment: @HemantMalpote Well, there you have your answer: if it's any arbitrary enumeration, use `Enum` and cast.

Comment: Krumelur and  haim i had update the question please check it.  Krumelur can you tell me how to cast it. As i am getting x as null in case enum.

Comment: The code in your example doesn't compile. What is TMember? Any enumerator?